# Why is the class information for this html element not accessed by Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In my HTML for my file I have a div with the id "divNavyBox."  The code is below.

```
<div id="divNavyBox" class="box" onmouseover="animated.doAnimation()"></div>
```

Note that once the mouse hovers over it, it executes the doAnimation() from var animated.

```
var animated = {

el : document.getElementById("divNavyBox"),

doAnimation : function() {
    if (el.className=="box") {

        el.className="boxAlt";
    }
    if (el.className=="boxAlt") {
        el.className="box";
    }

}

};
```

I want it to switch between these two cs classes once the method doAnimation is executed.  However, it doesn't do anything.  I put an alert statement inside of the if(el.className="box" and it didn't ring up as I executed the function, even though the class really IS box.  The two CS classes that I want to be used are listed below:

```
.box {

    width: 100px;

    height: 100px;

    background-color: navy;

}
.boxAlt {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;  
background-color: red;
}
```

Why does the boolean statement el.className="box" keep returning false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you assign **boxAlt** if current = **box**

```
if (el.className=="box") {
    el.className="boxAlt";
}
```

here you switch back if current is **boxAlt** *which is allways true* if the class has been **box** from the beginning.

```
if (el.className=="boxAlt") {
    el.className="box";
}
```

Change it to something like:

```
doAnimation : function() {
    el.className = el.className == "box" ? "boxAlt" : "box";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`el.className = "box"` is not a Boolean statement, it's an assignment.

`el.className == "box"` is a boolean statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three problems with your code:

I wonder why there is a `;` before `onmouseover`.

Then you use `el.className="box"` in the `if()` which assigns `"box"` to `className`. Use `==` to compare.

Lastly, `el.style.className` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I fixed those three problems and they're now put into the original post.  Even though I fixed those three problems the doAnimation function still does not change the class of divNavyBox.

Comment: Add `alert(typeof el)` as the first command in `doAnimation`. It's probably `undefined`